# OmniPersistence JPA library can only handle 23 entities?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a JSF projekt using EclipseLink and OmniPersistence. Everything is working fine, I define the entities as follows:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import org.omnifaces.persistence.model.GeneratedIdEntity;

@Entity
public class PeterOPeter extends GeneratedIdEntity<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

and

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import org.omnifaces.persistence.model.GeneratedIdEntity;

@Entity
public class PeterOPeter extends TimestampedEntity<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

So the following columns will be generated:

- created
- lastModified
- id

I reached 23 different entities, no problem. Then I add another entity so it will be 24, a problem occurs. When I load an already persisted entity all generated columns (created, lastModified, id) are suddenly null. All other colums are correct. When I comment any of the entities so I go back to 23, everythings works again. Wow this is strange. Does anyone know if there is a limit on how many entities can be handle via OmniPersistence library?

Comment: There is no such limit as far as I'm aware. I've worked on a project which had ~150 entities and it was working fine there.

Comment: You've shown two different PeterOPeter class definitions extending different classes. Hopefully you are using different class and entity names in your testing to avoid issues where you might be requesting the wrong class back. Otherwise, show the 24th class and how you are persisting, loading it and if there is data in the database for it.